# Can you remove log4j.jar from /usr/share/java on Rhel7/Tomcat7 - Log4J Vulnerability Removal

Tags: log4j, tomcat7, rhel7

Trying to determine if I can completely remove the log4j.jar from the /usr/share/java location on the server.  It's showing up as the vulnerable 1.2.17 verison in our security scans.  I've tested removing it and I don't seem to see any issues in Tomcat or RHEL caused by not being there.  Just looking for confirmation that this jar isn't needed or what it is being used for or where it might be referenced.  Thanks.

Note: I'm not a SA, just filling in until they can hire someone.  Please let me know if you have any questions on this situation.

Removed Jar from location and tested functionality.

Comment: If it is in `/usr/share/java`, it is part of an RPM package (`log4j`). Try removing the package to see, which software uses it (Tomcat doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove log4j. I suggest you do the following:

1  Search wich rpm package installed that library:
rpm -qf /usr/share/java/log4j.jar
example log4j-1.2.17-18.el7_4.noarch

2 Execute a remove of that package:
yum remove log4j-1.2.17-18.el7_4.noarch

3 Before you confirm, validate that the dependencies don't affect your system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If its a RHEL7 install the 1.2.17 version is patched (backported) the nessus findings are false